# Select change eventListener triggered several times (the number increasing on every change)

Tags: javascript

I need the chosed option to be added to the table after the submit button is pressed (the button is mandatory). The first chosen option is added only once, when the option in select element is chosen for the second time, both 1st and 2nd options are added, on the third 3 change, all the previous changes are added to the table and in the end the new one.
[I read the topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280348/select-change-event-is-triggering-multiple-times), but I still can't get what can be done about it? Whenever I remove the button event listener, the problem goes away, every change is added only once to the table, but I can't discard the button, information must be added just after "submit".

My code

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    let select = document.getElementById("select");
    let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
    let btn = document.getElementById("submit_btn");

    select.addEventListener("change", function(){        
        let val = this.value;
        let text = this.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

        showOption(val, text);
    });  

    function showOption(val, text){
        //when Submit is pressed
        btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            let tr = document.createElement("tr");
            //add info about the value of the chosen option
            let td1 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.innerHTML = val;
            //add info about the text of the chosen option
            let td2 = document.createElement("td");
            td2.innerHTML = text;
            tr.append(td1, td2);
            tbl.append(tr);
        });
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <select id="select">
            <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_btn">
    <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
            <th>Option ID</th>
            <th>Option itself</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output after choosing "Option 1", "Option 2" and "Option 3" consecutively:

```
Option ID   Option itself
   1        Option 1
   2        Option 2
   3        Option 3
```

What I actually get:

```
Option ID   Option itself
   1    Option 1
   1    Option 1
   2    Option 2
   1    Option 1
   2    Option 2
   3    Option 3
```

Comment: Because that is what you coded. Every change you add the event listener. Just don't do that. Move `showOption(val, text);` outside the change event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every change you add the event listener. Just don't do that.
Re-reading, you do not event need to save the value and text when you change the select. Just read it in the click

Note I do not capture the click if the select is on the first option

I also fixed your table HTML

Here I assume One option added per click

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const select = document.getElementById("select"),
    tbl = document.getElementById("tbl"),
    btn = document.getElementById("submit_btn");

  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (select.selectedIndex === 0) return; // don't add the first 
    const val = select.value;
    const text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    //add info about the value of the chosen option
    let td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.innerHTML = val;
    //add info about the text of the chosen option
    let td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.innerHTML = text;
    tr.append(td1, td2);
    tbl.append(tr);
  });
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_btn">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Option ID</th>
      <th>Option itself</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a version where you can change the select and each time it will add the option to an array and then write them all when submit is clicked

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const select = document.getElementById("select"),
    tbl = document.getElementById("tbl"),
    btn = document.getElementById("submit_btn");
  let collection = [];

  select.addEventListener("change",function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex === 0) return;
    collection.push({val: this.value,text:this.options[this.selectedIndex].text});
  })

  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const html = collection.map(item => `<tr><td>${item.val}</td><td>${item.text}</td></tr>`)
    tbl.innerHTML=html.join("")
    collection=[]; // reset
  });
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_btn">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Option ID</th>
      <th>Option itself</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A stack is needed from here out. Push the input onto a stack and pop it off when submit is pushed.

Comment: I assume OP meant choose option 1 and click submit, then choose option2 and click submit

Comment: `I need the chosed option to be added to the table after the submit button is pressed`

Comment: `Information must be added just after "submit".`

Comment: @ShanerM13 In case you are correct, I added a new version

Comment: No, no. You are totally right. I just didn't read.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using:**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    let select = document.getElementById("select");
    let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
    let btn = document.getElementById("submit_btn");
    let val = '';
    let text = '';

    select.addEventListener("change", function(){        
        val = this.value;
        text = this.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    });  

    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            if(val == '') { alert("Please Choose Option"); }
            else {
               let tr = document.createElement("tr");
               //add info about the value of the chosen option
               let td1 = document.createElement("td");
               td1.innerHTML = val;
               //add info about the text of the chosen option
               let td2 = document.createElement("td");
               td2.innerHTML = text;
               tr.append(td1, td2);
               tbl.append(tr);
            }
    });

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <select id="select">
            <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_btn">
    <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
            <th>Option ID</th>
            <th>Option itself</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have modified the solution now check.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have modified the solution